# How to use "sagemaker.workflow.quality_check_step.ModelQualityCheckConfig" for a Logistic Regression problem

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-clarify

I would like to know, how to use "**sagemaker.workflow.quality_check_step.ModelQualityCheckConfig**" for a Logistic Regression problem. In this link: [sagemaker-pipeline-model-monitor-clarify-steps.ipynb](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/model-monitor-clarify-pipelines/sagemaker-pipeline-model-monitor-clarify-steps.ipynb), there is an example that shows how to use this class in a regression problem.

[Regression example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JojSr.png)

But my case is different because I'm using a XGBoost Classifier that uses binary:logistic as objective function, this model gives my the probability of having a possitive class.

The results of the batch transform step of my use cases look like the following:

[Output of the batch transform step of my use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9KEK.png)

The first column is the label values and the second is the inferences of the model.

So, I don't know how to use this class (ModelQualityCheckConfig) for a binary classification problem like my case. Is there a way in which I can specify a threshold for the predictions or something like that?

I tried something like this:

[First try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmbVB.png)

And of course the processing job failed because It says that the inference values have too many classes and this is because those values are the probabilities and not just 0 or 1.

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can specify a threshold for the predictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the threshold for Binary classification using attribute
`probability_threshold_attribute="0.5",`
Remember, for binary classification your training dataset label should be 1/0 not 1.0/0.0. Typecast label into int. As mentioned in this post: https://repost.aws/questions/QU8EShrCQdT7eJQq8PUGyGmQ/sagemaker-model-quality-check-step-for-binary-classification-is-failing-with-error-message-more-than-two-classes-are-not-supported-in-binary-classification